# Entendendo o sistema de permissões do Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, autenticação, permissões

Tenho um app chamado **forms_and_models** que uso para estudo. Na [documentação do Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) diz que:

> Assumindo que você tenha uma aplicação cujo *app_label* é **foo** e um modelo chamado **Bar**, para testar as permissões básicas, você deve usar:
>
> - para adicionar: `user.has_perm('foo.add_bar')`
> - para mudar: `user.has_perm('foo.change_bar')`
> - para deletar: `user.has_perm('foo.delete_bar')`

Através do administrador, eu adicionei a permissão: **forms_and_models | author | Can add author** ao meu usuário. Seguindo o modelo da documentação, eu deduzi que para testar se um usuário tem a permissão de adicionar um autor, eu poderia executar o código seguinte:

`"""O usuário abaixo existe e é o que eu configurei a permissão acima"""
user = User.objects.get(username='junior')
user.has_perm('forms_and_models.add_author')`

Contudo essa linha de código sempre retorna false. O que eu estou deixando passar despercebido sobre o sistema de permissões?

Comment: Testei seu código aqui e parece funcionar corretamente (usei o Django 1.4 entretanto, mas o resultado deve ser o mesmo). Experimente `user.get_all_permissions()` e veja o que acontece. A propósito, esse usuário é superusuário ou não, membro da equipe ou não, está ativo ou não? (por exemplo, se ele estiver inativo, `get_all_permissions` vai listar as permissões corretamente, mas `has_perm` vai retornar `False`)

Comment: @mgibsonbr está ativo sim, não é superusuário nem membro da equipe. O resultado de `user.get_all_permissions()` retorna `set()`. Alguma informação a mais que eu possa dar?

Comment: Não faço ideia do que possa estar acontecendo, então... :( No meu teste, `user.get_all_permissions()` deu `set([u'forms_and_models.add_author'])`. Quando você volta lá no admin, aparece essa permissão pro seu usuário?

Comment: Sim, consigo salvar quaisquer que sejam as permissões para esse usuário, só que pela linha de comando não vai :(

Comment: Pergunta besta: você fechou a linha de comando e abriu de novo (ou pelo menos, pegou o usuário de novo do BD em uma nova consulta `get`) depois de salvar o usuário via admin?

Comment: @mgibsonbr achei o que estava errado e respondi minha pergunta, dá uma olhada aí embaixo. Depois que você testou meu código e tudo ocorreu bem, me veio à mente que deveria testar com o shell do Python 2 pelo **manage.py** (eu estava iniciando com o Python 3). Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o que estava acontecendo. O problema era apenas que eu estava iniciando o shell interativo via terminal usando o Python 3, dessa maneira:
`python3 manage.py shell`

Quando eu abri utilizando o comando `./manage.py shell`, que usa o shebang do arquivo **manage.py**, tudo ocorreu conforme a documentação. Agora as permissões são listadas normalmente. Nunca tive problemas como esse utilizando o Python 3 para iniciar o shell. Vá entender.

Obrigado!